# What is a correct way to bind document level key events in AngularJS specific only to a certain route/controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page app that opens a gallery. I want to bind document level keyup event (for keyboard gallery controlls) only when the gallery is open, ie. when route matches

```
.when('/reference/:galleryId/:imageId/', { templateUrl: '/partials/gallery.htm', controller: 'galleryController', controllerAs: 'reference' })
```

and I want to unbind it when I leave this route.

One thing that might be a problem is, I block reloading the view between images within the same gallery with this:

```
.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function (path, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                $route.current = lastRoute;
                un();
            });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
}])
```

Demo (Click on "Fotografie" to open the gallery)
http://tr.tomasreichmann.cz/

Angular wiz to the rescue?

Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: I'm curious about the code that block reloading. What does it do? Change the url back to a previous value?

Comment: No, I think it overrides locally the $location.path function used to redirect a page. if reload === false it waits for locationChangeSuccess event and marks the previous path as current path. If reload is true, original $location.path is used instead.
But I didn't write this. It took a lot of googling before I found this solution. I don't know if this is the best practice and I would love to hear from an Angular PRO how was I supposed to do that.

Comment: However it doesn't change the URL, so you still have an option to change URL without reloading the ng-view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could bind a keyup event to `$document` in your controller's constructor and then unbind the event when the controller's `$scope` is destroyed. For example:

```
.controller('galleryController', function ($scope, $document) {
  var galleryCtrl = this;

  function keyupHandler(keyEvent) {
    console.log('keyup', keyEvent);
    galleryCtrl.keyUp(keyEvent);

    $scope.$apply(); // remove this line if not need
  }

  $document.on('keyup', keyupHandler);
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $document.off('keyup', keyupHandler);
  });

  ...
});
```

There will be nothing left behind when the view become inactive.

If you feel it isn't right to do this in the controller, you could move this into a custom directive and place it in a template of the view.

Comment: Nice! I tried it and it definitly worked to some extend. Wierd thing though. Every interaction was one keypress behind.
I pressed Right arrow - nothing
I pressed Left arrow - it moves right
I clicked close button - it moves left

I think I am missing an apply somewhere ...
Didn't happen with `$broadcast('my:keyup', $event)` so I'll stick with that, but your code is probably alright. I'll try it next time.

Comment: May be you need a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the event handler.

Comment: For me it always needed use of `$scope.$apply`, in case that helps anyone else. Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I stuck with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
  lang="cz"
  ng-app="profileApp"
  ng-keyup="$broadcast('my:keyup', $event)" >
```

Not sure if this is good practice, but it registers within my controller

```
$scope.$on('my:keyup', function(event, keyEvent) {
    console.log('keyup', keyEvent);
    galleryCtrl.keyUp(keyEvent);
});
```

And doesn't do anything when the current route is not active

I found this answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/document$20level$20events/angular/vXqVOKcwA7M/RK29o3oT9GAJ

There is another way to bind it globally which wasn't my goal, the original code in question did what I needed.

Comment: This way, the keyup event handler will always exists and broadcast an event when click even if the view is not currently active.

Comment: You are right. Not ideal, but worked 'out of the box'